# Error !!! CloudFormation template validation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm designing redis cluster using cloudformation template and during the validation of the template I'm facing this error "**Template contains errors.: Template format error: JSON not well-formed. (line 151, column 2)**"

Below is the cloudformation script

```html
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
   "Metadata": {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
      "f60e2d2e-b46b-48b1-88c8-eecce45d2166": {
        "size": {
          "width": 60,
          "height": 60
        },
        "position": {
          "x": 320,
          "y": 70
        },
        "z": 2,
        "parent": "71508a33-8207-4580-8721-c3688c4a0353",
        "embeds": [],
        "ismemberof": [
          "a63aacbd-1c6e-4118-8bbe-08a5bc63052a",
          "55eb37aa-e764-49ac-b8fe-3eddb2ea77ad"
        ]
      },
      "a63aacbd-1c6e-4118-8bbe-08a5bc63052a": {
        "size": {
          "width": 60,
          "height": 60
        },
        "position": {
          "x": 320,
          "y": 160
        },
        "z": 2,
        "parent": "71508a33-8207-4580-8721-c3688c4a0353",
        "embeds": []
      },
      "0291abc8-9c50-491b-8400-e1f7f8b22118": {
        "source": {
          "id": "f60e2d2e-b46b-48b1-88c8-eecce45d2166"
        },
        "target": {
          "id": "a63aacbd-1c6e-4118-8bbe-08a5bc63052a"
        },
        "z": 1
      },
      "55eb37aa-e764-49ac-b8fe-3eddb2ea77ad": {
        "size": {
          "width": 60,
          "height": 60
        },
        "position": {
          "x": 440,
          "y": 70
        },
        "z": 2,
        "parent": "71508a33-8207-4580-8721-c3688c4a0353",
        "embeds": []
      },
      "7aa270dd-1131-4dc4-8913-dfaf44a3815d": {
        "source": {
          "id": "f60e2d2e-b46b-48b1-88c8-eecce45d2166"
        },
        "target": {
          "id": "55eb37aa-e764-49ac-b8fe-3eddb2ea77ad"
        },
        "z": 2
      },
      "71508a33-8207-4580-8721-c3688c4a0353": {
        "size": {
          "width": 610,
          "height": 600
        },
        "position": {
          "x": 20,
          "y": 10
        },
        "z": 1,
        "embeds": [
          "55eb37aa-e764-49ac-b8fe-3eddb2ea77ad",
          "a63aacbd-1c6e-4118-8bbe-08a5bc63052a",
          "f60e2d2e-b46b-48b1-88c8-eecce45d2166"
        ]
      }
    }
   },
   "Parameters" : {
     "CacheNodeType" : {
     "Description" : "The compute and memory capacity of the nodes in the Cache Cluster",
     "Type" : "String",
     "Default" : "cache.m3.medium",
     "AllowedValues" : ["cache.t2.micro", "cache.t2.small", "cache.t2.medium", 
      "cache.m3.medium", "cache.m3.large", "cache.m3.xlarge", "cache.m3.2xlarge",
      "cache.t1.micro", "cache.m1.small", "cache.m1.medium", "cache.m1.large",
      "cache.m1.xlarge", "cache.c1.xlarge", "cache.r3.large", "cache.r3.xlarge",
      "cache.r3.2xlarge", "cache.r3.4xlarge","cache.r3.8xlarge", "cache.m2.xlarge", 
      "cache.m2.2xlarge", "cache.m2.4xlarge"], 
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must select a valid Cache Node type."
     }
   },

   "Resources": {
    "RedisClusterReplicationGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "CacheParameterGroupName": {
        "Ref": "RedisClusterParameterGroup"
        },
        "CacheSubnetGroupName": {
        "Ref": "RedisClusterSubnetGroup"
        },
        "CacheNodeType" : { "Ref" : "CacheNodeType" },
        "Engine" : "redis",
        "EngineVersion" : "2.8.24",
        "NumCacheClusters" : 4,
        "Port" : 6879,
        "PreferredCacheClusterAZs" : ["us-east-1c","us-east-1d","us-east-1e"],
        "ReplicationGroupDescription" : "RedisClusterReplicationGroup",
        "SecurityGroupIds" : "sg-7ea72e07",
        "SnapshotRetentionLimit" : 0,
        "AutomaticFailoverEnabled" : true,
        "Metadata": {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
          "id": "f60e2d2e-b46b-48b1-88c8-eecce45d2166"
        }
      }
    },
    "RedisClusterParameterGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElastiCache::ParameterGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "CacheParameterGroupFamily" : "redis2.8",
        "CacheParameterGroupName" : "RedisClusterParameterGroup",
        "Description" :"RedisClusterParameterGroup"
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
          "id": "a63aacbd-1c6e-4118-8bbe-08a5bc63052a"
        }
      }
    },
    "RedisClusterSubnetGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElastiCache::SubnetGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "Description" : "RedisClusterSubnetGroups",
        "SubnetIds" : ["subnet-7854ab20", "subnet-eaa7039c", "subnet-988a00a5"]
      },
      "Metadata": {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
          "id": "71508a33-8207-4580-8721-c3688c4a0353"
        }
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: you are just missing a closing } at the end of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Metadata": {
    "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
      "f60e2d2e-b46b-48b1-88c8-eecce45d2166": {
        "size": {
          "width": 60,
          "height": 60
        },
        "position": {
          "x": 320,
          "y": 70
        },
        "z": 2,
        "parent": "71508a33-8207-4580-8721-c3688c4a0353",
        "embeds": [],
        "ismemberof": [
          "a63aacbd-1c6e-4118-8bbe-08a5bc63052a",
          "55eb37aa-e764-49ac-b8fe-3eddb2ea77ad"
        ]
      },
      "a63aacbd-1c6e-4118-8bbe-08a5bc63052a": {
        "size": {
          "width": 60,
          "height": 60
        },
        "position": {
          "x": 320,
          "y": 160
        },
        "z": 2,
        "parent": "71508a33-8207-4580-8721-c3688c4a0353",
        "embeds": []
      },
      "0291abc8-9c50-491b-8400-e1f7f8b22118": {
        "source": {
          "id": "f60e2d2e-b46b-48b1-88c8-eecce45d2166"
        },
        "target": {
          "id": "a63aacbd-1c6e-4118-8bbe-08a5bc63052a"
        },
        "z": 1
      },
      "55eb37aa-e764-49ac-b8fe-3eddb2ea77ad": {
        "size": {
          "width": 60,
          "height": 60
        },
        "position": {
          "x": 440,
          "y": 70
        },
        "z": 2,
        "parent": "71508a33-8207-4580-8721-c3688c4a0353",
        "embeds": []
      },
      "7aa270dd-1131-4dc4-8913-dfaf44a3815d": {
        "source": {
          "id": "f60e2d2e-b46b-48b1-88c8-eecce45d2166"
        },
        "target": {
          "id": "55eb37aa-e764-49ac-b8fe-3eddb2ea77ad"
        },
        "z": 2
      },
      "71508a33-8207-4580-8721-c3688c4a0353": {
        "size": {
          "width": 610,
          "height": 600
        },
        "position": {
          "x": 20,
          "y": 10
        },
        "z": 1,
        "embeds": [
          "55eb37aa-e764-49ac-b8fe-3eddb2ea77ad",
          "a63aacbd-1c6e-4118-8bbe-08a5bc63052a",
          "f60e2d2e-b46b-48b1-88c8-eecce45d2166"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "Parameters": {
    "CacheNodeType": {
      "Description": "The compute and memory capacity of the nodes in the Cache Cluster",
      "Type": "String",
      "Default": "cache.m3.medium",
      "AllowedValues": [
        "cache.t2.micro",
        "cache.t2.small",
        "cache.t2.medium",
        "cache.m3.medium",
        "cache.m3.large",
        "cache.m3.xlarge",
        "cache.m3.2xlarge",
        "cache.t1.micro",
        "cache.m1.small",
        "cache.m1.medium",
        "cache.m1.large",
        "cache.m1.xlarge",
        "cache.c1.xlarge",
        "cache.r3.large",
        "cache.r3.xlarge",
        "cache.r3.2xlarge",
        "cache.r3.4xlarge",
        "cache.r3.8xlarge",
        "cache.m2.xlarge",
        "cache.m2.2xlarge",
        "cache.m2.4xlarge"
      ],
      "ConstraintDescription": "must select a valid Cache Node type."
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "RedisClusterReplicationGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "CacheParameterGroupName": {
          "Ref": "RedisClusterParameterGroup"
        },
        "CacheSubnetGroupName": {
          "Ref": "RedisClusterSubnetGroup"
        },
        "CacheNodeType": {
          "Ref": "CacheNodeType"
        },
        "Engine": "redis",
        "EngineVersion": "2.8.24",
        "NumCacheClusters": 4,
        "Port": 6879,
        "PreferredCacheClusterAZs": [
          "us-east-1c",
          "us-east-1d",
          "us-east-1e"
        ],
        "ReplicationGroupDescription": "RedisClusterReplicationGroup",
        "SecurityGroupIds": "sg-7ea72e07",
        "SnapshotRetentionLimit": 0,
        "AutomaticFailoverEnabled": true,
        "Metadata": {
          "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
            "id": "f60e2d2e-b46b-48b1-88c8-eecce45d2166"
          }
        }
      }
    },
      "RedisClusterParameterGroup": {
        "Type": "AWS::ElastiCache::ParameterGroup",
        "Properties": {
          "CacheParameterGroupFamily": "redis2.8",
          "CacheParameterGroupName": "RedisClusterParameterGroup",
          "Description": "RedisClusterParameterGroup"
        },
        "Metadata": {
          "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
            "id": "a63aacbd-1c6e-4118-8bbe-08a5bc63052a"
          }
        }
      },
      "RedisClusterSubnetGroup": {
        "Type": "AWS::ElastiCache::SubnetGroup",
        "Properties": {
          "Description": "RedisClusterSubnetGroups",
          "SubnetIds": [
            "subnet-7854ab20",
            "subnet-eaa7039c",
            "subnet-988a00a5"
          ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
          "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
            "id": "71508a33-8207-4580-8721-c3688c4a0353"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Any JSON parser will tell you what the issue is. The last element need not have a ',' and the JSON needed one more '}' to get validated properly. I haven't checked if the script passes the cloudformation validation but, it passes the JSON parsing

Comment: Thanks Naren. After fixing this issue, the validation is saying that " Template contains errors.: Invalid template resource property 'RedisClusterParameterGroup' " . I don't understand why it is not accepting this resource.

Comment: You are using **RedisClusterParameterGroup** as a Ref inside **RedisClusterReplicationGroup**. The paranthesis was not closed for the replication group so the parameter group was never a separate entity. Once the paranthesis is closed properly for the replication group the parameter group is now an separate resource. I am expecting the Ref to pick it up now. I have edited the json accordingly. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes, Naren. It worked looks like it's really a painful task to debug the templates especially with the parenthesis.

Comment: I received this error upon executing the template "Encountered unsupported property Metadata". Do you have any idea about this error ?

Comment: Another tip besides using a JSON parser, use your text editor's feature that shows matching brackets/parenthesis etc.  Put your cursor on a bracket etc. and see if the matching bracket is where you expect it to be.

Comment: Thanks Mark for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

One way to avoid this whole set of JSON errors is to switch to YAML syntax, which is supported by Cloudformation. You can convert your JSON document to YAML at
https://www.json2yaml.com/
and then just use that. I find YAML much easier to maintain without the quotes, braces, and commas.